# Regarding split() method in Java String API

Tags: java, string

I wrote the following Java code for testing the `split()` method in the String API.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "10 5";
        String[] integers = str.split(" ");
        int numOfInt = integers.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfInt; i++) {
           System.out.println(integers[i]);
        }
     }
}
```

I noticed that the above code gives me an output of
`10`
`5`
which is to be expected.
However, if I change the contents of `str` to `" 10 5"` then I get

`10`
`5`
as output. I don't understand why the output is different from the one above. If I am splitting `str` by using `" "` as a delimiter, then I thought that all `" "` will be ignored. So what is the extra space doing in my output?

EDIT: I tried `"  10 5"` and got


`10`
`5`
as output.

Comment: It's not an extra space; it's a zero-length string.

Comment: Nope, every space creates a new field. Try `10  5` (2 spaces between the two numbers) for another experiment.

Comment: They don´t ignore it, It just splits the String on each instance of the delimiter wheter it has content or not.

Comment: Because the first element of the Array will be "", the second "10" and the third "5". Split will put "" as first char if you have the delimiter at index 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a delimiter as the first character, `split` will return an empty String as the first element of the output array (i.e. `" 10 5".split(" ")` returns the array `{"","10","5"}`).

Similarly, if you have two consecutive delimiters, `split` will produce an empty String. So `"10  5".split(" ")` will produce the array `{"10","","5"}`.

If you wish leading and trailing whitespace to be ignored, change `str.split(" ");` to `str.trim().split(" ");`.

Comment: Consider `str = ",10,,,5,".split(",")`. 
The first character is the delimiter `','`, so we add the token before that, `""`, to the array `str`. Then the remaining string is: `"10,,,5,"`. Now the first character is not `','`, so we move on until we find `','`, and add the token before that, `"10"`, to the array `str`. Now we're left with `",,5,"`. The first character is `','` so we add the token before that, `""`, to `str`, and repeat for the next character, which is also `','`.

Comment: (Continued) Lastly we're left with "5,". The first character `'5'` is not `","`, so we move on to `','` and add the token before that, `"5"`, to the string and we're done. So `str = {"", "10", "", "", "5"}`? Is that what's going on here?

Comment: @Vizuna Yes, that's what's going on here.